# How to manually reuse the error route?

Tags: ember.js

## How to manually reuse the error route?

So you can create a template called error, and the user will be (intermediately) transitioned to it if before/-/after model returns a promise that rejects or maybe also if they throw an error i think.

#### a) Is it bad practice of me to reuse this template/route for when I fail to handle some serious error that was not in the model hooks? If that is the case, why?

#### b) If it's not bad practice to reuse the error-template/route, how do you actually make the transition to the error route properly?

To understand, I'd like to see

- An error route declaration in router.js (or statement that you don't use one)
- An example of transitioning to the error route with code

Answer (score 2):

a) i dont know if its bad practice or some kind of bad pattern

b) this is how i run my own code whenever an error happens, no matter what kind of error afaik:

```
// The ApplicationRoute
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        error: function(error) { Ember.onerror(error) },
    },

    setupErrorHandling: function() {
        Ember.onerror = function(error) {
            // console.assert(false, error);
            if      (error && error.stack)  { console.error(error.stack); }
            else if (error)                 { console.error(error); }
            this.intermediateTransitionTo('error', error);
        }.bind(this);
    }.on('init'),
});
```